# Javascript: get total checked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox

I have a form and want to find, how many checkboxes have been checked?

My Checkbox id will be same, `event_id` and name will be something like this: `data[Noncompetitor][is_black][4]`

How can i?

Let me know ASAP.

Thanks !

Comment: Post some HTML and some JS attempts :)

Comment: The id of an element has to be unique. Having the same id for all the checkboxes doesn't work.

Comment: *"My Checkbox id will be same, `event_id`"* Then you'll have trouble. `id` values **[must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute)** in the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have a reference to your [form's element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-40002357), it's easy to loop through the elements:

```
function countChecked(form) {
    var index, element;
    for (index = 0; index < form.elements.length; ++index) {
        element = form.elements[index];
        // You may want to check `element.name` here as well
        if (element.type.toUpperCase() == "CHECKBOX" && element.checked) {
            ++checked;
        }
    }
    return checked;
}
```

There are lots of ways to get a reference to the form element. For instance, give the form an `id` and use [`document.getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-getElBId).

So if your form's `id` is "foo", for instance, then:

```
var checkedCount = countChecked(document.getElementById('foo'));
```

---

**Off-topic**: A lot of this stuff can be made a *lot* easier using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) to smooth over browser differences, give you rich ways to traverse to elements via CSS selectors, and such.

For example, the above can be written using jQuery like this:

```
var checkedCount = $("#foo :checkbox:checked").length;
```

...which says, *'find all checked checkboxes that are descendants of the elemen twith the `id` "foo"'* and then uses the length of the resulting jQuery object (jQuery objects are array-like).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code to get the number of check box checked.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var index = 0;
        function check()
        {
            index++;
            document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = "You have Checked \t"+index+"\t checkboxes";
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="check()"/>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="check()"/>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="check()"/>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="check()"/>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="check()"/>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="check()"/>
    <div id="text"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: and what about when it is uncheckd?