# On click button a validation on checkbox if user selects more than one checkbox, it should allow if user selects only one checkbox

Tags: javascript, onclick

On a button click JavaScript Validation should be: If a user select one checkbox it should allow to process further to any script, but when user selects more than one checkbox it should prompt that "you can select only one check box"

I am not getting to What javaScript I should write ?

```
<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='checkbox' name='check1' value=12> Q.12 Torronto in located in  ?</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='checkbox' name='check1' value=4> Q.4 Columbo is the capital of which country ?</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='checkbox' name='check1' value=16> Q.16 Most used  social suite ?</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='checkbox' name='check1' value=19> Q.19 Largest State ?</td></tr>
```

Function call

```
<td><input type='submit' type='Edit' value='EDIT' formmethod='post' formaction='/~xyz/cgi-bin/Project/CheckEdit.py' onclick='return(CheckedOne())'></td></tr>
```

The JS which I tried:

```
function Checked() {

               var d = document.myForm.check1;
               var arr = 0;
               for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                   if (d[i].checked) {
                   arr++;
                   alert(arr);
                   }
               }
                  if (arr == 1) return true;
                  else {
                      alert("Please select only one Checkbox");
                      return false;
                  }
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do better using the approach by sravis using jQuery.

Here are the issues in your original code:
You call the function `CheckedOne` in the HTML but have a different name in the JS (`Checked`).

Also, use `document.getElementsByName('check1');` to get the 
array.

See http://jsbin.com/iTiQOFIX/1/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery length will get you total checked boxes

http://jsfiddle.net/yAz2j/

```
$(".subtn").live('click', function() {

    var total = $('.check1:checked').length;

    if(total > 1) {
        alert(" Checked : "+total);
        // your code
    } else {
        alert("Checked only one!");
    }

    return false;

});
```

Also check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5594976/1570901